# Can I process the fields first and then process the files in Nodejs busboy

Tags: node.js, busboy

I am using the Busboy to upload the form data which contains the file and some text fields.

Every thing is working fine i am able to get the post parameters and file.

How can i achieve this: 
First I need to process the fields data and save in Db and process the file and update in same record in DB.

The busboy is first process the file and then process the fields.

```
req.pipe(req.busboy);
req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
    console.log("Uploading: " + filename);
    console.log("fieldname: "+fieldname);
});
req.busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated) {
    var jsondata = JSON.parse(val);
});
```

Any suggestions

Answer (score 10):

Simple: just put your fields before your files in your form. Example:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="foo">
  <input type="text" name="bar">
  <input type="file" name="baz">
</form>
```

Comment: Can't it be control from the server side?

Comment: No, the client is the one that orders the request data.

Comment: I don't see how the `async` module would help you with this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

busboy will read the data in the order which we append formData

```
form.append('field',value);
form.appnd('file',file);
```